# Redirect Customer To Product Details Page After Login in Shopware 6

Tags: shopware, shopware6

How do I redirect customers to the product details page after login.

I tried the following code

```php
{% set redirectTo = "frontend.detail.page" %}
{% set redirectParameters = "d7cca22753c94d08b6078a58057b3129" %}
```

but I keep getting the error message

```
Some mandatory parameters are missing ("productId") to generate a URL for route "frontend.detail.page".
```

Comment: Please check the correct answers as accepted, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirect parameters need to be provided as a JSON string.

You can do that by encoding

```
{% set redirectParameters = {productId: 'd7cca22753c94d08b6078a58057b3129'}|json_encode %}
```

or providing the JSON string directly

```
{% set redirectParameters = '{"productId": "d7cca22753c94d08b6078a58057b3129"}' %}
```